# How to programmatically show the text selection widget

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need users to be able to select text and then perform some functions on it. So, I added an EditText and made it read-only.

I do not want users to see the default (Select, Copy, Paste...etc) dialog upon selecting text, so I disabled the long press action, but at the same time I want to show the two selection markers.

Is there a way two start selection mode through code?

Comment: What do you want the user to be able to do once the selection markers are show? Sounds like you've disabled most of the functionality.

Comment: I disabled the long press action to prevent the (copy/paste) dialog from appearing, but this also disabled selection altogether. I wonder if it is possible to enable selection without the dialog.